# Retrieve image from msaccess database in java

Tags: java, ms-access

I have Stores an Image in Ms access Database and datatype of column is OLE OBJECT.
But i am Unable to retrieve the Image from database.
Please help..

When i try to Open Image its show Error

**Unknown File Format or file not found.**

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: i m reading the image stored in bytes and trying to save it on disk. File is created but it shows error.

Comment: Ok. *What* error? Show us your code! Show us the error message! (edit your question to include those things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing we need to do is set the column type as `OLE Object`. While saving the data into the column of type `OLE Object`, save the data as `byte array`, while retrieving the image from the column read the value, put the value into `byte array` and then convert the `byte array` to `image type` and display the same. This is very simple.